# Pushing a bare repo after removing secrets using bfg

Tags: bfg-repo-cleaner

I've used BFG to remove secrets from my repo's history. Now when I try to push the modified bare repo I get:

```
 ! [remote rejected]   refs/pull/823/head -> refs/pull/823/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
```

many times. These secrets were in some of the commits that were in a merged branch. How can I overcome it?

I've tried to open a PR but since it is a bare repo, branches are not relevant here.